# Remove notification bar in Samsung Galaxy Tab 3

Tags: custom-roms, notification-bar, customization, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7

Is there a way to remove the notification bar on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a launcher app to do such things. Try using launchers available on PlayStore, like [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en). Launcher will give you access to hiding notification bar, configuring desktop grid, playing around with doc and so on.